# Push Up animation in android?

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-animation, feed

I need to implement a news feed in my android application. It should animate like the push up animation in API Demos. But In my application I get A object Array which contains image and its heading. How can I animate the news feed using ViewFlipper or any other way ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [AniationFactory.java](http://sherifandroid.blogspot.com/2011/09/animation-factory.html) there is the function `outFromBottom()`

So lets say you have `yourView` and you want to add it to a vertical `LinearLayout` called `feedLL`.

Use the following code:

```
Animation animation = AnimationFactory.inFromBottom();
animation.setDuration(1000);
yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
yourView.setAnimation(animation);
feedLL.addView(yourView);
yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBILE);
```